# Nginx rewrite with cache control, impossible?

Tags: php, nginx, caching, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have multiple css files, so since I was already using php, I created a script that just opens these files and output all at once.

So the client just need to fetch one css file instead of 4.
To make it look like an css file, I have added a rewrite rule:

```
location ~ /css/test.css {
    access_log off;
    rewrite ^ /css/test.css.php;
}
```

Apparently the cache-control I had in place before does not apply for some reason:

```
location ~* \.(?:png|ico|woff2|js|css)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

So I tried to apply it directly:

```
location /css/test.css.php {
    add_header Content-Type text/css;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    expires 1M;
}
```

None of them works. Any idea?
Its good to have just 1 css file but that its not cached is really bad.

Comment: What does your `location ~ \.php$` block look like?

Comment: That was the issue, my php catched it, so I needed to add = and it worked. As it seems to overwrite it, before php is executed.